# Subsets of linearly independent sets are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

If $ S = \{ v_1,\dots,v_k\} \subset V (k \in \mathbb{N})$ is linearly independent and $T \subseteq S$, prove that $T$ is linearly independent.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Do you understand the definition of "linearly independent"?

Comment: my understanding of linear independence is that when scalars ${a_1 a_2 ... a_n} \in \mathbb{F}$ (not all a values =zero) are applied to S you would get 0 in the end. But im not sure how to show that here. So fall all i have said that Say there exits a set $\{a_1 a_2 a_3 .. \}$ and multiplied that with S to get aS. Now im trying to figure out how to show that it is equal to zero and not all of a is zero

Comment: *"when scalars {a, b,c,..} (not all zero) are applied to S you would get 0 in the end"* is not a sentence I can make sense of, and it causes me to believe that you don't really understand the definition.

Comment: I would apply the definition directly.

Comment: Also, you should know that for this question and future questions: writing the question-statement alone is not generally considered enough.  You should also provide a bit of context to help us understand where you are, for example, with a brief description of your attempts so far.

Comment: i will do that in the future sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A set of vectors $A$ is **linearly independent** if whenever $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are in $A$ and $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ are scalars satisfying
$$
c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n=0,
$$
then $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$.

To show that $T$ is linearly independent, we fix vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in $T$ and $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ scalars satisfying
$$
c_1x_1+\cdots+c_nx_n = 0.
$$
Then in particular $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are in $S$. Hence the fact that $S$ is linearly independent implies $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, let's try to understand the definition of linear independence a bit better: we say the set $S$ is linearly independent if for any scalars $c_1,\dots,c_n$, the only way we can have
$$
c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0
$$
is if $c_1 = c_2 = \cdots = c_n = 0$.

In order to understand the proof we're trying to go through, it might help to go through a bit of a "mini-proof".

> **Claim:** If $T = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\}$ is linearly independent, then so is $S = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.

**Proof:** We want to show that if $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are scalars such that $c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 = 0$, then it must be the case that $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.

So, suppose that $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are such scalars.  We can then say that
$$
c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 + (0)v_4 + (0)v_5 = 0
$$
However, the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_5\}$ is linearly independent.  So... *[where do we go from here?]*

Comment: I like this approach to proof-learning.  Will steal for my classes.

Comment: @Randall Glad you like it. As a rule of thumb, I think that anything you can do to get rid of the $\dots$ in a step is going to make for something more digestible.

Comment: oh. i see i had gotten the definition of linear dependent and independent mixed up.

Comment: @LKRC Ah, now I understand your earlier comment.  Linearly independent just means **not** linearly dependent, if you prefer to think about it that way.

Comment: I think this proof idea may be wrong. How could you conclude in the next step that $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$? Since this would only be possible for unknow coefficients for $c_4$ and $c_5$?

Comment: you can do it without assuming $c_4$ and $c_5$ to be zero just do  $c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 = 0 $ which gives us $ u_1 v_1+ u_2 v_2 + u_3 v_3 + u_4 v_4 + u_5 v_5=0=c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 $ giving us $ (u_1-c_1)v_1+ (u_2-c_2) v_2 + (u_3-c_3) v_3 + u_4 v_4 + u_5 v_5=-c_1 v_1 - c_2 v_2 - c_3 v_3=0$ which prooves $u_3-c_3=0$ and with that $u_3=0$, equally for $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Comment: @pindakaas the definition of linear independence does not require that the coefficients $c_4$ and $c_5$ are "unknown".  We have 
$$
c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 + 0 v_4 + 0 v_5 = \vec 0
$$
the definition of linear independence tells us that this can only occur if all coefficients (including those which are known) are zero.

Comment: @pindakaas I agree, however, that you alternate proof is also correct.

Comment: my problem with your argument is, that we only get $c_1=c_2=⋯=c_n=0$ simultaniously from the linear independence, not that we can set part of the coefficients to zero and then conclude things about the equation. But I can not produce an example of nonsence coming from this method either... sorry to bother you

Comment: (helaas) @pindakaas I understand your problem with my argument. I maintain, however, that my argument is correct.