# Show that a subset of a set of linearly independent vectors is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, set-theory

> Show that if $S_1\subset S$ and $S$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, then $S_1$ is also linearly independent.

I don't understand what the question is asking because the answer seems trivial.

1. What does it mean to say that a subset is linearly independent? Is it that its elements are all linearly independent?
2. How do you show that $S_1$ is linearly independent if it is not simply to say that since every element in $S$ is linearly independent, so every element in its subset is linearly independent?

Comment: 1. is just the definition of linearly independent vectors, in this case for those being elements of a set $S$. Note that only finitely many are considered each time (so no infinite sums). For details see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). 2. follows directly from applying the definition given in 1. It seems that you need to review step 1. first. That alone shows that the talsk is "non-trivial".

Comment: @Erik Your question is addressed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2394979/81360)

Comment: To whoever voted to close this post, this is **not** a post with multiple questions. The only problem here is the exercise statement, "Show that if $S_1\subset S$ and $S$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, then $S_1$ is also linearly independent." Bullets 1 and 2 are OP's thoughts and questions regarding the problem statement, which fulfill the need for "context".

Comment: Linear independence is a property of a set of vectors, not a property that is possessed (or not) by each vector individually.  It is about *relations* among the vectors, i.e. whether a linear combination of them equals zero without simply taking all the scalar multiples to be zero.  This is likely a duplicate of earlier Questions.  I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

Students sometimes speak sloppily; often it doesn't matter much but here it seems to me the whole problem is caused by using the language imprecisely:

There is no such thing as an "independent vector"! There is such a thing as an independent *set of vectors*. If it were true that a set $S$ is independent if and only if every element of $S$ is an independent vector then it would be completely trivial that a subset of an independent set is independent. But that's not the definition...